# ListView Header apperance flat

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I hope all you are fine and doing well.
I'm facing one problem in listview. I have some headers is listview which are appearing flat and not according to windows 7 theme.
Kindly see the attach pictures.[image]

Comment: It does not look like visual styles is enabled.  Is this C# or VB?

Comment: Its on VB. And its not appearing like that on one form. Its appearing like that in all forms.

Comment: well that would be because `EnableVisualStyles` is a member of `Application` so it *would* impact all forms.  Does your app start from a Main Form or  Sub Main?

Comment: Its starts from main()

Comment: Means, i created a module for that and running my application from that module. Module contain main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you start your app from a `Sub Main` you are not using the VB "Application Framework" which automatically enables visual styles.  This is easy to fix:

```
Public Sub Main()
    ' use this before any WinForms elements are 
    ' created or referenced!
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()        ' to add

    '... your other code

    Application.Run(New MainForm)            ' start up form

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much all of you.
There is slight modification in your answer @plutonix. We have to call Applcaition.DoEvents() also.

Comment: Most of my apps start from Sub Main and I never have to use `DoEvents` (ever).  There might be something else at play in your case that it seems needed. `DoEvents` is almost never a good idea...but glad it worked!

Comment: yes may be, because I'm using devexpress controls also.

Comment: be sure to invoke it very, very early in your Sub main and it should be fine without DoEvents.

Comment: yes, its now working fine by calling it very early. Thank you thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Why do answers to these questions always involve `Application.Run()`?  It's not needed.  Neither is `DoEvents`.  The following is the basis for a practical forms application beginning with Sub Main().  It involves a user-designed form that is instanced and shown, and utilizing a pack object to send a response from said form, back to the calling subroutine, once the form is closed.

```
Option Strict

Public Module EntryPoint
    Public Sub Main()

        'Optional, if you want the Vista/Windows7 theme on your controls
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()

        'Show a form
        dim response As New MyCustomPack
        Using form As New MyCustomForm(response)
            form.ShowDialog()
        End Using

        'Do something with the response
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The response is {0}", response.Value))

        'The program now ends
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class MyCustomForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Private WithEvents _CtrBtnChoice1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button = Nothing
    Private WithEvents _CtrBtnChoice2 As System.Windows.Forms.Button = Nothing
    Private _Response As MyCustomPack = Nothing

    Public Sub New(ByRef Out_Response As MyCustomPack)
        _Response = Out_Response
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Setup form controls here
        _CtrBtnChoice1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        _CtrBtnChoice2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        With _CtrBtnChoice1
            'Set button size, location, text, etc
        End With
        With _CtrBtnChoice2
            'Set button size, location, text, etc
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub _CtrBtnChoice1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles _CtrBtnChoice1.Click
        _Response.Value = 11111
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub _CtrBtnChoice2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles _CtrBtnChoice2.Click
        _Response.Value = 22222
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyCustomPack
    Public Value As Integer
End Class
```